# Spring websocket: how to send to all subscribers except the message sender

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am following the quick-start guide on Spring websocket with sockJs and Stomp here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

At this point, my code looks like to one from guide and works as intended. I have a controller class with a method accepting incoming messages and sending them back to all who subscribed on the topic.

What I want to do, is to change the code, so my `@MessageMapping` annotated method sends response to all subscribers **excluding the one who send the message to the controller in the first place** (because the sender is also subscribed to the same topic, but i dont want the sender to keep receiving messages it send itself, it is kind of a loop I guess).

I have seen many docs describing how to send a message to a single subscriber, but have not yet seen on describing how to send to all but one - the initial message sender.

Is there any built-in way to do this easily in Spring websocket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so i've managed to find some solution which works for me at this point of time:

i was able to filter subscribers by principal user name.

I got all simp users form `org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.SimpUserRegistry`,
and a current sender from `org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor`.

My code looks something like this:

```
  @MessageMapping("/game/doStuff")
  public void gameGrid(DoStuffMessage doStuffMessage,
      StompHeaderAccessor headers) {
    sendTo("/game/doStuff", doStuffMessage, headers);
  }

  private void sendTo(String destination, Object payload, StompHeaderAccessor headers) {
    Optional<String> user = Optional.ofNullable(headers.getUser())
        .map(Principal::getName);

    if (user.isPresent()) {
      List<String> subscribers = simpUserRegistry.getUsers().stream()
          .map(SimpUser::getName)
          .filter(name -> !user.get().equals(name))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

      subscribers
          .forEach(sub -> simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sub, destination, payload));
    }
  }
```

Client is subscribing to `/user/game/doStuff`

It works for now. What I am worried about is if this code can scale horizontally - if someone has any insight on this I'd greatly appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

For who need. I hope it will be helpful:

Controller:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.DestinationVariable;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SessionSubscribeEvent;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SessionUnsubscribeEvent;

import com.example.demo.provider.JwtProvider;

@Controller
public class CommentPostController {
    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    private final HashMap<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> userCommentPostSessions = new HashMap<>();
    
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;
    
    @MessageMapping("/comment-post/create/{postId}")
    public void send(@Payload String message, @DestinationVariable Integer postId, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) throws Exception { 
        String senderSession = headerAccessor.getUser().getName();
        Integer senderId = userCommentPostSessions.get(postId).get(senderSession);
        for(Entry<String, Integer> entry: userCommentPostSessions.get(postId).entrySet()) {
            if(!entry.getKey().equals(senderSession)) {
                this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(entry.getKey(), "/topic/comment-post/"+postId, message + " from UserID: " + senderId);                          
            }
        }
    }
            
    
    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketUnSubcribe(SessionUnsubscribeEvent event) {
        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

        String destination = headerAccessor.getDestination();
        if (destination.startsWith("/user/topic/comment-post/")) {
            String[] destinationSplit = destination.split("/");
            Integer postId = Integer.parseInt(destinationSplit[destinationSplit.length - 1]);

            String senderSession = headerAccessor.getSessionId();
            userCommentPostSessions.get(postId).remove(senderSession);

            if (userCommentPostSessions.get(postId).size() == 0)
                userCommentPostSessions.remove(postId);
        }
    }
    
    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketSubcribe(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

        String destination = headerAccessor.getDestination();
        if (destination.startsWith("/user/topic/comment-post/")) {
            String senderSession = headerAccessor.getSessionId();
            String token = headerAccessor.getNativeHeader("token").get(0);
            Integer senderId = jwtProvider.getAccountIdFromJWT(token);

            String[] destinationSplit = destination.split("/");
            Integer postId = Integer.parseInt(destinationSplit[destinationSplit.length - 1]);

            if (!userCommentPostSessions.containsKey(postId)) {
                userCommentPostSessions.put(postId, new HashMap<>());
            }
            userCommentPostSessions.get(postId).put(senderSession, senderId);
        }
    }
}
```

Interceptor:

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UserInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        try {
            StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

            if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(headerAccessor.getCommand())) {
                headerAccessor.setUser(new UserPrinciple(headerAccessor.getSessionId()));
            }           
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private UserInterceptor userInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app", "/user");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/realtime").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
        registry.addEndpoint("/realtime").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000").withSockJS();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(userInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Principle:

```
import java.security.Principal;

public class UserPrinciple implements Principal {
 
    private String name;
 
    public UserPrinciple(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
}
```

Client(I use ReactJS + StompJS):

```
const [client, setClient] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    // config stomp
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
        const stompClient = new Client({
            brokerURL: "ws://localhost:9006/realtime",
            connectHeaders: {
                token: token
            },
            reconnectDelay: 2000,
        });

        // Connect to the WebSocket server
        stompClient.activate();

        stompClient.onConnect = () => {
            console.log("Connect");
            stompClient.subscribe("/user/topic/comment-post/" + post.postId, (message) => {
                setComments((previous) => [...previous, message.body]);
            }, {
                token: token
            });
            setClient(stompClient);
        }
        return () => {
            client?.deactivate();
        }
    }

}, []);

const onSendComment = (e) => {
    if (client) {
        const message = e.currentTarget.value;
        client.publish({
            destination: "/app/comment-post/create/" + post.postId,
            body: message
        });
    }
};
```